# Radius of convergence of this complex power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $R > 0$ be the radius of convergence of a power series
$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n $. Show that
the radius of convergence of the power series
$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty
\frac{a_n}
{n+1}(z -a)^{n+1}$ is greater than or
equal to $R$.
I have one approach that uses Cauchy Hadamard theorem to conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{a_n}{n+1}|^{1/n} \leq |a_n|^{1/n}$. Hence $R_2\geq R_1$
Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: It seems hard to find something simpler than these two lines…

Comment: But I'm not sure if this is the correct way

Comment: This is one way. You also can prove that if the given series converges, the new series also converges. It should use normal convergence of the given series on every closed disk with radius $<R$.

Comment: @Bernard but I also have to show that radius of convergence is $\geq $ original R

Comment: If it is $\ge r$ for all $r<R$, it is $\ge R$. Isn't it clear to you?

Comment: No, it's not clear, can you elaborate?

Comment: FYI, the radius of convergence is exactly R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n+1}(z-a)^{n+1} =
(z-a)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n+1}(z-a)^n,$$
$$\left|\frac{a_n}{n+1}\right|\le|a_n|,$$
and use direct comparison.